# Legendary badge not show progress

Tags: support, reputation, badges, badge-progress

On StackOverflow, I've earned 200 daily reputations 3 or 4 times, but if check on the badge progress, it keeps showing 0 days.

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It seems hitting the reputation cap with rep earned from Docs doesn't count for those badges. Whether that is wanted or a bug is another question...

Comment: I hope this is wanted, otherwise rare badges will become as meaningless as reputation currently is. To put it another way, if it is possible to get the Legendary badge from farming rep on Documentation, I will be very tempted to relinquish mine -- it won't mean anything anymore.

Comment: ok, thank you! I agree with this, otherwise, this badge will become too easy.
I think this should be explicit on the badge documentations

Comment: No, in this case is because of doc reputations